# Angular ui-router: $stateParams empty inside my directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

In my angular app, I have created a custom directive for a `navbar`, which controller takes in `$stateParams` to access a variable called `lang`, as so:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, LANG) {

    $urlRouterProvider
        .otherwise('/' + LANG['EN'].shortName);

    $stateProvider
        .state('proverb-list', {
            url: '/:lang',
            templateUrl: 'components/proverb-list/proverb-list.html',
            controller: 'ProverbListCtrl as vm'
        })
        .state('proverb-single', {
            url: '/:lang/:proverbId',
            templateUrl: 'components/proverb-single/proverb-single.html',
            controller: 'ProverbCtrl as vm'
        });
});
```

When I access the state `proverb-list`, the controller named `ProverbListCtrl` does see `$stateParams.lang` correctly, but my navbar directive cannot. When I `console.log($stateParams)` all I get is an empty object.

This navbar is outside my `ui-view`:

```
<navbar proverbial-navbar></navbar>

<div ui-view></div>

<footer proverbial-footer></footer>
```

Is that the problem? How can I access the actual $stateParams inside my directive?

**EDIT:** directive code below, as asked:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('proverbial')
        .directive('proverbialNavbar', directive);

    function directive() {
        var directive = {
            restrict: 'EA',
            templateUrl: 'components/shared/navbar/navbar.html',
            scope: {
            },
            link: linkFunc,
            controller: Controller,
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            bindToController: true
        };

        return directive;

        function linkFunc(scope, el, attr, ctrl) {

        }
    }

    Controller.$inject = ['LANG', 'ProverbFactory', '$stateParams'];

    function Controller(LANG, ProverbFactory, $stateParams) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.languages = LANG;
        console.log($stateParams);
        vm.currentLang = LANG[$stateParams.lang.toUpperCase()];

        activate();

        function activate() {
            vm.alphabet = ProverbFactory.getAlphabet();
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: Please pass the stateparams as a value with `=` sign in the directive. You should able to access scope models in directive that way. So may be you want to assign the $stateParams to a model before passing it to directive. Remember that you might need child interitance scope/shadow dom in these cases even if you have isolated scope for directive. So create a super controller for all these. Ui-router allows you to specify multiple views may be you can make use of that

Comment: Yes, the navbar being outside of the UI view is probably the issue. Think about it. The navbar will get instantiated once, before you even enter the state. So when the navbar code runs, it hasn't entered the state yet. Show your directive code to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

You should not access `$stateParams` in this directive when it is independent of the state. Since your navbar is outside of the `ui-view`, its controller can be called before the `ui-router` has initialized the `$stateParams` of the state you are interested in. Remember that your navbar controller is called only once, when the navbar is initialized and not every time the state changes.

**Alternative:** What you can do is turn your `currentLang` field into a function. The function can retrieve the value from the `$stateParams` when needed:

```
vm.currentLang = function() { return LANG[$stateParams.lang.toUpperCase()] };
```

Make sure you change `currentLang` to `currentLang()` everywhere in your template.